# binding.pry in Rails View: NameError: undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pry, pry-rails

I use Rails 4 with the gems byebug, pry-rails, pry-byebug, pry-stack_explorer.

When i replace in a view file:

```
  <td class="subtotal"><%= order.display_item_total %></td>
```

with

```
  <td class="subtotal"><%= binding.pry %></td>
```

and type inside the console where the rails server process is running and the execution stopped at the pry breakpoint:

```
order.inspect
```

i get the error message:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `order' for #<ActionView::OutputBuffer:0x007fdf13d99bb8>
```

When i replace binding.pry with order.inspect i get the object info of order in the browser.

I would expect that I should be able to get the object order inside the pry session in the console. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
In the beginning of the console output:

```
From: /Users/standardnerd/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb @ line 166 ActiveSu
pport::SafeBuffer#safe_concat:

    165: def safe_concat(value)
 => 166:   raise SafeConcatError unless html_safe?
    167:   original_concat(value)
    168: end
```

Does this impact the scope of the variables?

Comment: Hm, that _should_ work.

Comment: Try replacing `<%= binding.pry %>` with `<% binding.pry %>`

Comment: @John, the issue still persists :(.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
<td class="subtotal"><%= binding.pry %></td>
```

Is attempting to output the response from `binding.pry` to the view, and I think this is triggering your `SafeConcatError` and I suspect you're not accessing the correct binding.

Better would be to do...

```
<% binding.pry %>
<td class="subtotal"><%= order.display_item_total %></td>
```

...so doing the `pry` immediately before you attempt to  render the total.

Comment: Really simple answer: Use `<% binding.pry %>` not `<%= binding.pry %>`.